# console is giving Undefined name Context on run ( flutter )

Tags: flutter, dart

I am new to flutter and  don't know why am i receiving this kind of error. `Undefined name Context` how do i fix it and any other suggestions related flutter would be great. I don't even know what does this means. Thank you

```
void main() {
       runApp(
         MaterialApp(
           home: Scaffold(
             appBar: AppBar(
               title: Text('Welcome to, Dice Game'),
             ),
             backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
             body: DicePage(),
             drawer: Drawer(
               child: ListView(
                 children: <Widget>[
                   ListTile(
                     title: SafeArea(
                       child: Text('About us',style: TextStyle(
                           fontSize: 20.0,
                           fontWeight: FontWeight.w200
                       ),),
                     ),
                     onTap: (){
                       Navigator.push(
                         context,  //this line is causing the error
                         MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SecondRoute()),
                       );
                     },
                   ),
                 ],
               ),
             ),
           ),
         ),
       );
     }
```

Comment: As it says, there is no context above the tree, Navigator check for an inherited widget in the tree, but there is none (the first Navigator is created in the material app and you're doing all the widgets in the same method), try moving your Scaffold to a Stateless widget or wrap the Drawer with a Builder so it can check for a Navigator above that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should wrap your MaterialApp in a StatelessWidget or State class like this:

```
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}


class MyApp extends StatelessWidget{
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Welcome to, Dice Game'),
        ),
        backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
        body: Stack(children: [],),
        drawer: Drawer(
          child: ListView(
            children: <Widget>[
              ListTile(
                title: SafeArea(
                  child: Text('About us',style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 20.0,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w200
                  ),),
                ),
                onTap: (){
                  Navigator.push(
                    context,  //this line is causing the error
                    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SecondRoute()),
                  );
                },
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

we need to wrap your MaterialApp with [StatelessWidget](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StatelessWidget-class.html) or [StatefulWidget](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StatefulWidget-class.html).